# How to produce output of a previous git commit?

Tags: git, github

I have a **local git repo** which contains LaTex (tex, bib, etc. ) files of a write-up.

I want to produce PDFs of a previous commit to see how it looked sometime ago.

*P.S: In fact, I want to produce PDFs of all the commits.*

So, my approach is as follows:

- Run `git rev-list master` to list of all git commits in terms of hashes. Note down the specific hash (say, `<hash_of_the_commit>`), such that I want to see my PDFs at that point.
- Run `git fetch .git --depth=1 <hash_of_the_commit>` and `git checkout`
- Run the commands to generate the PDF. For example, `pdflatex write_up.text`, `bibtext write_up.aux`, `pdflatex write_up.text`, `pdflatex write_up.text`
- The output PDF produced should be the same as that of a PDF produced when `<hash_of_the_commit>` was commited?

The command `git rev-list master` gives the list of all git commits in terms of hashes.

However, it is **still producing the PDF of the latest (newest) commit**, and **not that of `<hash_of_the_commit>`**. I am sure I am missing a step here. What am I missing? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

It is not quite clear what your script does and how it affects your working directory.

If it adds or modifies any files. You can use `git reset --hard`  and `git clean` to return to a clean state.

If it switches to another commit hash you can use `git checkout -` to return to the previous branch you were working on.

**Edit**

After reading the modified questions - it seems that what you are missing is actually checking out the correct hash:

```
git checkout <hash_of_the_commit>
```

Also the entire part of `git fetch` seems redundant. It is a local repo, you check the revisions on your master. There is nothing you need to fetch from remote server.

Comment: Added more clarity to my question.

Comment: It seems that all you need to do is `git checkout <hash>`

Answer (score 1):

> How to build or compile a specific git commit?

Get the commit by fetching a branch or a tag which includes the commit, checkout the commit, and build/compile the code.